# List categories of a Blog with Angular ngFor directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just want to list the categories of a Blog in Angular. When I use ngFor, It shows a list of the categories but is bringing in some repeated ones, like if it were bringing all the blogs and not just the categories that some of them share. Hope I was clear on this question.

This is my html:

```
<aside class="categories">
     <h2 class="aside-title">Categorias</h2>

     <ul *ngFor="let data of datas; index as i">
        <li class="nav-elipse-blue"><a [routerLink]="['/pagina',datas.category]" title="Blog CSS 
        articles">{{ data.category.name }}</a></li>
     </ul>

</aside>
```

Comment: Hello Bao Huynh, Can you be more specific, since I am a newbie? Do I have to create a Pipe or something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to remove duplicates from your array.

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects), you can do this:

```
const uniqueCategorias = datas.filter((value, index) => {
  const _value = JSON.stringify(value);
  return index === obj.arr.findIndex(obj => {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === _value;
  });
});
```

and use it:

```
 <ul *ngFor="let data of uniqueCategorias; index as i">
    <li class="nav-elipse-blue"><a [routerLink]="['/pagina',datas.category]" title="Blog CSS 
    articles">{{ data.category.name }}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and in TypeScript file:

```
uniqueCategorias; 

getUniqueCategorias(){
    uniqueCategorias = datas.filter((value, index) => {
        const _value = JSON.stringify(value);
        return index === obj.arr.findIndex(obj => {
            return JSON.stringify(obj) === _value;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello StepUp!  I think you cannot call a variable from the 'ngFor ' directive., because you wrote : const uniqueCategorias

Comment: @LuisAlejandroLópezdeAnda yeah, you are right. I've added TypeScript realization of this method. Please, see my updated reply

Comment: Hello StepUp, you seem to have so many badges. I wolud like to share to you this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849947/show-the-slug-in-the-url-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-blog-in-angular-and-strapi

Comment: Hello SetUp!, You are right about it. I remember about this topic. The thing is that you were very right about removing duplicates from my array. It was just the code did not work for me. I found this other way that it may be similar with yours. I first looped my array, and then, I filtered the data. I posted the code that worked for me below.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a separate `categories` variable for your class, or if you can pull the list of categories straight from the database. To get the unique categories you can use JS's "set" data structure to filter out unique items: `uniqueCategories = new Set(data.map(item => item.category.name))`

Angular:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'component'
  templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
export class Component {
  data = ....
  uniqueCategories = new Set(this.data.map(item => item.category.name))
}
```

HTML

```html
<ul *ngFor="let category of uniqueCategories">
  <li>{{category}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove first the duplicates from an array and after that you have to use *ngFor.

You can remove duplicates in different ways:

1. Using ***Set***

   ```
   let data = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];
   let uniqueData = [...new Set(data)];
   ```
2. Using ***forEach()*** and ***include()*** :

   ```
    let data = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];

    let uniqueData = [];
    data.forEach((c) => {
       if (!uniqueData.includes(c)) {
       uniqueData.push(c);
     }
    });
   ```

There are other methods but these are more understandable.

After that in your ***HTML***

```
     <ul *ngFor="let data of uniqueData">
        <li>{{category}}</li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myCategories(datas: any){
 let newArr = [];
 let uniqueArray:any;
  datas.forEach((item, index) => {
    newArr.push(item.category.name);
    uniqueArray = newArr.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item)===pos;
    })

     
  });
  return uniqueArray;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).