# Show the Slug in the URL when a user clicks on a Blog in Angular and Strapi

Tags: javascript, angular, blogs, strapi

I want the URL to show the slug instead of the ID when a user clicks on a blog. I am using Angular as a frontend framework where I created a service to call the data from the backend. I made the backend with Strapi. Anytime I choose a blog from the view, the URL shows the ID and not the Slug.

```
http://localhost:4200/pagina/3
```

And what I want is this:

```
http://localhost:4200/pagina/the-shrimp-is-awesome
```

This is my Angular Service. As you can see the first method named 'getData' calls all the blog entries sorted by ID DESC, whereas the second method named 'getDataById' calls the detail of a unique Blog setting the parameter as ID, in which I think, I should do some proper adjustment.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StrapiService {

  REST_API: string ='http://localhost:1337/articles';
  //https://strapi-dot-gmal-api-313723.uc.r.appspot.com/
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }




  getData():Observable<any>{

    let API=this.REST_API + '?_sort=id:DESC';
    return this.httpClient.get(API,{headers:this.httpHeaders}) .pipe(
      map((data:any) => { 
        return data;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
    
  }




  getDataById(id):Observable<any>{

    let API_ID=this.REST_API+"?id="+id;
    return this.httpClient.get(API_ID,{headers:this.httpHeaders}) .pipe(
      map((data:any) => { 
      
        return data;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
    
  }


 
}
```

This is my blog-routing.module, where I tried to change the path from: pagina/:id' to 'pagina/:slug', but it also did not work.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { PaginaComponent } from './blog/pagina/pagina.component';
import { CategoriasComponent } from './categorias/categorias.component';
import { DetalleComponent } from './categorias/detalle/detalle.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
    { path: 'pagina/:id', component: PaginaComponent },
    { path: 'categorias/:category', component: CategoriasComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BlogRoutingModule { }
```

This is an image of my browser that show the fields of an entry of my Strapi backend. The field 'slug' is also populated.

[image]

Comment: If you are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it

Comment: Ok, That is very helpfull StepUp! Thanks for this advice!

Comment: Do you have an existing enum or something you can use to associate the id to the slug already? If so you could make a directive for example that converts the url to the appropriate slug url but ideally you'd do this on the backend so the return data already included it as perhaps an additional key/value in the object to use in the binding. Since we don't have insight into those kind of details it's kind of tough to provide a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: Hello Chris W.!  I shared an image of a browser request, where you can see the Posts that come from the Strapi Backend,As you can see the 'slug' was also populated, but I am not pretty sure how to show it in the URL instead of the ID.

Comment: If you just want to change the URL then you need to change the html template of the component that is clicked for routing to occur. If the link is currently something like <a [routerLink]="['/pagina', id]">Link to the Shrimp is Awesome Blog</a> then change it to <a [routerLink]="['/pagina', id, slug]">Link to the Shrimp is Awesome Blog</a> to get URL http://localhost:4200/pagina/3/the-shrimp-is-awesome .  Or leave out the id from the URL altogether but have to look it up or pass it in a different way.

Comment: Hello Katherine!. Thanks for your answer! It solved the issue. How can I give you credit for this answer, since there is no green tick to click?

Comment: By the way Katherine, If you´d like to post an answer, I will click the green tick.  You also mentioned in your comment something interesting about 'leave out the id from the URL', but I think It would be some other good question topic.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a custom controller from your strapi backend and override the default findOne params to slug.

By default strapi use's id field to query a single item in a collection.

[Here is a link to the reference in their documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#adding-a-new-controller)

Hope that helps?